# Форматирование исходников с исключениями

Tags: c, форматирование

Вот такой вот странный вопрос вдруг возник. Какие программы для форматирования исходников (в первую очередь на C, другие языки интересуют меньше) позволяют указывать области для исключений?

Столкнулся с куском кода, в котором пришлось расставлять не только осмысленные, но и фейковые комментарии (`/* */`), чтобы не потерять ясность после форматирования:

```
static int a[] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        /* '0' - '9' */
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        /* */
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        /* 'A' - 'Z' */
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
        28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
        /* */
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        /* 'a' - 'z' */
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
        28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
        /* */
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
       /* ... up to 255 ... */ };
```

Для [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/), [bcpp](http://invisible-island.net/bcpp/) и [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) этого хватает, но тут нужно в каждом частном случае подбирать варианты. И теоретически захотелось иметь возможность помечать неформатируемые блоки какими-то спецмаркерами.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/features/

Comment: Это IDE, а не форматёр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это ж надо было столько времени тормозить, разглядывая маны...

1. [AStyle, раздел Disable Formatting](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Disable_Formatting)
2. [Indent, 1.10 Disabling Formatting](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html#SEC13)